# extension's popup.html does not load properly on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

i have made one chrome extension and below is my manifiest.json file

```
   {
     "update_url":"http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
     "name": "Example",
     "version": "1.0",
     "manifest_version": 2,
     "description": "Example Dictionary",

      "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "16x16.png",
      "icons": ["128x128.png"],
      "default_title": "Dictionary",
      "default_popup": "index.html"  
   },

 "icons": { 
    "16" : "16x16.png",
    "48" : "48x48.png",
    "128": "128x128.png"  },

   "content_scripts": [
   {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "css" : ["jqm-demos.css","jquery.mobile.min.css"],
  "js": ["index.js","jquery.js","jquery.mobile.min.js"]
 }
  ]

}
```

now when i load popup.html page is looking like

[image]

but when i load extension it will be look like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest file should look like this:

```
{
   "update_url":"http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
   "name": "Example",
   "version": "1.0",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "description": "Example Dictionary",

   "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "16x16.png",
    "icons": ["128x128.png"],
    "default_title": "Dictionary",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"  
   },

   "icons": { 
     "16" : "16x16.png",
     "48" : "48x48.png",
     "128": "128x128.png"
   },

   "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
     "css" : ["jqm-demos.css","jquery.mobile.min.css"],
     "js": ["index.js","jquery.js","jquery.mobile.min.js"]
   }
   ]
}
```

According to your snapshot, you should assign "popup.html" to default_popup property. This field means which page do you want to be shown in popup dialog when user clicked the browser action icon.

Hope this is helpful for you.